# Parsing + Evaluating Expressions From JSON Object without using Eval()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing

I'm building a node app in which users are (ideally) able to define styling - for geographic data - using a series of JSON objects:

```
{
    "style":
        {
            "test": "year",
            "condition": "<= 1954 AND >= 1936",
            "color": "red"
        }
}
```

In the case above, I like to evaluate that style as

```
if (year <= 1954 && year >= 1936){
    object.color = red;
}
```

Is there an easy way to parse + evaluate such expressions/build them from such an object? I'm especially interested in letting people string together complex expressions built using <=, >=, ||, && etc.

I'd like to avoid using eval(), if possible.

Comment: You might want to check out my project language called Bianca: https://github.com/aaditmshah/bianca. It parses a program and spits out a JSON AST, which is kind of the exact opposite of what your program does. Nevertheless it may give you some valuable insights.

Comment: I definitely will check it out! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't wish to use eval, you would have to write your own little parser and create a definition language like this:

```
"condition": ["and", ["<=", 1954], [">=", 1936]],
```

This is a partial implementation you could consider:

```
function do_and(args, value)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
    if (!evaluate(args[i], value)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function evaluate(condition, value)
{
  switch (condition[0]) {
    case "and":
      return do_and(condition.slice(1), value);

    case "<=":
      return value <= condition[1];

    case ">=":
      return value >= condition[1];
  }
}
```

This is how you would use it:

```
var style = {
    "test": "year",
    "condition": ["and", ["<=", 1954], [">=", 1936]],
    "color": "red"
}, context = {
  "year": 1940
};    

if (evaluate(style.condition, context[style.test])) {
  console.log(style.color); // "red"
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/emibid/1/)

Comment: It's not clear from your answer whether you expect the user to provide this or the parser to parse into this format - the former is easier, of course :).

Comment: @nrabinowitz writing the parser didn't take that long, so I've included a partial implementation :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
switch (obj.style.operator){
    case '=':
    if (window[obj.style.condition] === obj.style){//assuming that the conditions are global
        object.color = obj.style;
    }
    break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Cool, I've implemented something similar but do you have any ideas as to how I can do more complex expressions? E.g. say a user wants to test if a certain value is >= 1954 OR <= 1936. I really don't want to write a case for every possible permutation.

Comment: @sir_kitty Then why didn't post about the complex expression instead of the one you can already do.